# Extracting a date from a log file?

Tags: python, datetime

I am attempting to create a DateTime object from a log file example string.

I have been trying to use a regex to parse this but it fails whenever I get to the format of the logfile which has a concatenated letter 'T' for the second half of the time. My test string is 'ERROR 2019-02-03T23:21:20 cannot find file'

```py
def convert_to_datetime(line):
    match = re.search('\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}', line)
```

I am struggling to get the full date out of the string. I have tried several regex but I think that I am using the wrong syntax.

Comment: `print(match.group() if match else "No match")` after `match`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if you want this, but generating a **datetime object** from a string can be very complicated if your string is kind of free style. But we have [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) package to help:

```
>>> import dateutil.parser
>>> s = 'ERROR 2019-02-03T23:21:20 cannot find file'
>>> dateutil.parser.parse(s, fuzzy=True)
datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 3, 23, 21, 20)
```

So if you like it, this is the function:

```
def convert_to_datetime(s):
    return dateutil.parser.parse(s, fuzzy=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to print the groups you matched too.

```
import re

s = 'ERROR 2019-02-03T23:21:20 cannot find file'
match = re.search('\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}', s)
print(match.group(0))
#2019-02-03
```

Also if you want to get the whole datetime string, you can do

```
import re
s = 'ERROR 2019-02-03T23:21:20 cannot find file'
match = re.search('\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}', s)
print(match.group(0))
#2019-02-03T23:21:20
```

After this if you want to get the datetime object you can use the https://pypi.org/project/python-dateutil/ library

```
from dateutil import parser
import re

s = 'ERROR 2019-02-03T23:21:20 cannot find file'
match = re.search('\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}', s)

#Datetime string
dt = match.group(0)

#Datetime object
dt_obj = parser.parse(dt)
print(dt_obj)
#2019-02-03 23:21:20

print(type(dt_obj))
#<class 'datetime.datetime'>
```

Or the best solution, use the `parser` function defined above with `fuzzy=True`

```
from dateutil import parser

s = 'ERROR 2019-02-03T23:21:20 cannot find file'
print(parser.parse(s, fuzzy=True))
#2019-02-03 23:21:20
```

Comment: Great, if the answer helped you! Please upvote and accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

Your close. You just need to get the result:

```
def convert_to_datetime(line):
    match = re.search('\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}', line)
    return match.group() if match else "No match"
```

**Test:**

```
t = convert_to_datetime('ERROR 2019-02-03T23:21:20 cannot find file')
print(t)
```

**Output:**

```
2019-02-03
```

Answer (score 0):

First, after reading https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html be careful than in Python 3 `\d` is not exactly equivalent to `[0-9]`,
Then,
be careful if there is no match `pattern.match` will raise an error
try something like

```py
pattern = re.compile('[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}')

if pattern.search(line):
    matches.append(pattern.search(line))
...
```

Comment: I never noticed that. Going to need to look into the error handling, thanks for pointing that out @sslloo

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what format you want the final string, here are 2 ways you can do this:

```
import re


def convert_to_datetime(line: str):
    match = re.search('\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}', line.strip('T')).group()
    match += ' | ' + re.search('\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}', line).group()
    return match


def cut_out_datetime(line: str):
    line = re.sub('ERROR ', "", line)
    line = re.sub('T', " | ", line)
    return line


s = 'ERROR 2019-02-03T23:21:20'
print('   Test string: ', s)
print()
print('Extract method: ', convert_to_datetime(s))
print(' "Trim" method: ', cut_out_datetime(s))


# OUTPUT:
   Test string:  ERROR 2019-02-03T23:21:20

Extract method:  2019-02-03 | 23:21:20
 "Trim" method:  2019-02-03 | 23:21:20

[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.05 seconds
```

There are other ways with positions and slicing, but this is most similar to your original code. Replace the | as you see fit or break the time and date into 2 separate strings ...