# Find min() and max() for each day in log file

Tags: python

New to Python, but I am stumped.

I have a text log file that starts each entry with a timestamp.  So :

```
03/17/2020 01:38:20 PM
03/18/2020 09:21:28 AM
```

I want to go through and create a two dimensional list that has one entry for each day as well as the earliest and latest timestamp found.  For instance, the list would contain [3/17/2020, 09:00:00 AM, 01:26:16 PM], [4/28/2020, 10:14:00 AM, 03:16:16 PM], with additional entries for each day.

Here is what I have so far (I blew away a previous attempt)

```
    lActDays = []
lActDayTimes = []
for item in lUAData:
    # Find the first space in the Time column.
    ispaceindx = item[0].find(' ')
    # Use the space as a delimiter, print everything before that - should be the date.
    sRecDay = item[0][0:ispaceindx]
    # Use the space as a delimiter, print everything after - should be the time.
    sRecTime = item[0][ispaceindx:].strip()
    if not sRecDay in lActDays:
        lActDays.append([sRecDay, [sRecTime]])
```

When I run this, it keeps appending [sRecDay, [sRecTime]] each time the for loop runs.  Its like the 'if not' condition isn't being run.  However, if I change the last line to lActDays.append(sRecDay), it works fine.  I get a list of unique days (but without a time)

Comment: What have you tried? Can you share code

Comment: share your code for more information. and the timestamp arrived from where?

Comment: From where do you get the earliest and latest timestamp ?

Comment: Example data would be useful.

Comment: Too many questions, not enough code. Parse the date into a datetime object. I would do dict['YYYYMMDD'] = [ tuple(datetime, linetext), ] but that's just opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You want to sort dates, you'll want to take advantage of the special properties of `datetime` objects that allow them to be sorted. Since you're reading in what looks to be a predictable format, you can also take advantage of `datetime` parsing and output [formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes):

```
from datetime import datetime

entries = ['06/05/2020 09:21:00 AM log file line 1 text',
           '06/15/2020 10:59:59 PM log file line 2 text',
           '06/25/2020 04:12:58 AM log file line 3 text',
           '06/05/2020 07:24:11 AM log file line 4 text',
           '06/15/2020 08:18:56 PM log file line 5 text',
           '06/25/2020 03:46:00 AM log file line 6 text',
           '06/05/2020 09:40:57 PM log file line 7 text',
           '06/15/2020 08:50:35 PM log file line 8 text',
           '06/25/2020 09:30:45 PM log file line 9 text',
           '06/05/2020 01:40:14 AM log file line 10 text']

fp = 'dummyfile.txt'
with open(fp, 'w') as dfile:
    dfile.write("\n".join(entries))


def get_daily_first_last(file_path):
    fmt = '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p'
    with open(file_path, 'r') as infile:
        data = {}
        for line in infile:
            dt, txt = datetime.strptime(line[:22], fmt), line.strip()
            day = dt.date().isoformat()
            if day in data.keys():
                data[day].append((dt, txt))
            else:
                data[day] = [(dt, txt)]

    for k, v in data.items():
        v = sorted(v)
        print(f"Day: {k}\nFirst entry: {v[0][1]}\nLast entry: {v[-1][1]}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    get_daily_first_last(fp)
```

You should get the output:

```
Day: 2020-06-05
First entry: 06/05/2020 01:40:14 AM log file line 10 text
Last entry: 06/05/2020 09:40:57 PM log file line 7 text
Day: 2020-06-15
First entry: 06/15/2020 08:18:56 PM log file line 5 text
Last entry: 06/15/2020 10:59:59 PM log file line 2 text
Day: 2020-06-25
First entry: 06/25/2020 03:46:00 AM log file line 6 text
Last entry: 06/25/2020 09:30:45 PM log file line 9 text
```

The "entries" list and "dummyfile.txt" is just an example to show it works. You asked for a list, but I really think you want a dictionary for this problem, so you can group data as you're parsing the file. I'm storing the entire line to the second item of a tuple in the `data` dictionary, so I can just print that out after it's sorted. The first item int the tuple is the datetime object that supports comparisons (e.g. sorting). The `v = sorted(v)` line returns a list that is sorted by the first item in each tuple (the datetime object).

Answer (score 0):

You have a bunch of questions in one. You really should break things down into separate tasks. That way, when you ask a question, it's one issue that you're working on, and you have code and data to demonstrate the issue, and your progress so far.

I put together this small demo based on the data you gave. Normally, you would want a regex to parse the date and separate it from the rest of the log data (see [Extracting a date from a log file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55905559/extracting-a-date-from-a-log-file/55906731))

But since your date is a fixed length, here's a super quick and dirty way to parse it, assuming it's date-space-text:

```
import datetime
import re
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint

logfile = [
    '03/17/2020 01:38:20 PM stuff goes here',
    '03/18/2020 08:21:28 AM earlier',
    '03/18/2020 09:21:28 AM more stuff in this line',
    '03/18/2020 11:21:28 AM later',
]

print ('parsing debug prints:')
mydata = defaultdict(list)
for line in logfile:
    timestamp, message = line[:22], line[23:]
    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(timestamp, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
    date_string = dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
    print (date_string)
    print (message)
    mydata[date_string].append((dt, message))
print()

print ('The full data structure:')
pprint(mydata)
print()
```

There's nothing special about finding the min/max items, assuming those items are a type that supports comparison. That is why I have put your timestamps into a datetime.

```
day = '03/18/2020'
list_of_records_from_day = mydata[day]
list_of_datetime_objects = [r[0] for r in list_of_records_from_day]
print ('The earliest timestamp on', day, 'is', min(list_of_datetime_objects))
```

Comment: I tried to break things out into separate lines for demonstration, but there is a list comprehension in there. Let me know if I need to elaborate.